# JSON.parse variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using JSON parsing for the below data (using JavaScript in XML).

```
<script>
vURI = 'rc_p\\49';
vData = '{ "params" : {"20":"1000","21":"5299","58":57}, "udata" : {"aaa":"bbb"}}';
vMessage = JSON.parse(vData)
</script>
```

In the vData, is it possible to use variable vThisDN instead of value "1000"?

```
<session:fetch method="'lib'" srcexpr="vURI">
<content expr= "vMessage"/>
```

Comment: <script>
vURI = 'rc_p\\49';
vThisDN = 1000;
vData = '{ "params" : {"20":"1000","21":"5299","58":57}, "udata" : {"aaa":"bbb"}}';
vMessage = JSON.parse(vData)
</script>  <session:fetch method="'lib'" srcexpr="vURI">
<content expr= "vMessage"/>
</session:fetch>

Comment: `vadata = '{ ...' + vThisDN + '...}'`. but you really shouldn't be building json yourself, or modifying it. it's VERY easy introduce syntax errors and kill the entire json block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. JSON is just a string so you can do something like this

```
<script>
vURI = 'rc_p\\49';
vThisDN = 1000;
vData = '{"params" : {"20" : "' + vThisDN + '","21" : "5299","58" : 57},"udata" : {"aaa" : "bbb"}}';
vMessage = JSON.parse(vData)
```

Comment: You can't have multi-line strings in JS like that.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to replace it **after** it gets parsed:

```
vURI = 'rc_p\\49';
vData = '{ "params" : {"20":"1000","21":"5299","58":57}, "udata" : {"aaa":"bbb"}}';
vMessage = JSON.parse(vData);
vMessage.params[20] = vThisDN;
```

This avoids the risk of syntax errors in the JSON by just keeping it as JS.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please consider accepting it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer